# Exclude index.html from express.static when serving React app with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I'm serving a create-react-app `build` using Express and appending some script tags to `index.html` before serving it. Since I'm manipulating the `index.html` file before serving, I don't want my `express.static` middleware to handle requests for `/` or `/index.html`. Here's what I've tried to make this work:

```js
app.use(
  [/^\/index\.html/, /^\//],
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../build"))
);

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  // logic to manipulate index.html
  res.send($.html());
});
```

But this just gives me a blank white screen even though the original html code gets inserted so I'm assuming that the static middleware is still handling the `/` request, it just stopped serving the other static assets.

How do I configure this code so my express.static stops overriding my `/*` route?

It's important that I keep the route as `/*` because I want that to handle all routes defined in react-router in the client application. So I can't move `express.static` middleware below the `/*` route otherwise that will override all requests for static assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a seperate handler for `index.html` and `/` before the static middleware:

```
function serveIndex(res) {
  res.send($.html());
}

app.get(["/index.html", "/"], (req, res) => {
    serveIndex(res);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../build")));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {  
    serveIndex(res);
});
```

Comment: I actually ended up with just importing an array of all the react-router routes and replaced `/*` with that. Then I just had to move `express.static` below that handler to make it work. But this seems like a simple workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass [`{index: false}`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#index) as the second argument of `express.static`, this will exclude `index.html` to be sent from the `build` directory.

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../build"), {index: false}));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {  
    // logic to manipulate index.html
    res.send($.html());
});
```